# Why does QGIS QuickMapServices' export of hi-res aerial maps return blank images?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, quickmapservices

Using the QuickMapServices plugin in QGIS 3.12.0 to load *Esri World Imagery (Clarity) Beta*, I noticed that every time I try to export large scale maps (e.g. 1:1,000) as high-resolution images  (at least 300dpi) the result is a blank image.

At 300 dpi, the largest scale export that works fine is 1:3,000. So there are no issues with aerial images at this scale and at scales lower than that (1:5,000, 1:10,000...).

I have tried exporting various file types, but the result is the same.

My colleague, who uses the same QGIS version and the same computer configuration (with 8GB RAM), has not experienced this issue.

I have re-installed QGIS, now using the latest version (3.12.1), but it still exports aerials as blank images.

Edit (further info):

- To save an aerial image in QGIS I simply go to **Project -> Import/Export -> Export Map to Image**
- It seems that exporting other aerial images (Bing) works fine.

Comment: Have you accidentally checked 'Disable tiled raster layer exports' with your large-scale exports (if using a specific Map Layout for large-scale maps)? Do you encounter the same issue with other less intensive basemaps (say Google Maps without satellite)? Also, how much RAM does your computer have (vs your colleague's)? I have experienced this issue before on a computer with 4GB RAM.

Comment: @she_weeds I have not come across an option to "Disable tiled raster layer exports" while doing an "Export Map to Image". I have now edited my question to add more details. Thanks!